# How to move the window by x number of pixels using Javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll

How do I scroll a window or webpage down using Javascript?  Basically, I want to move the web page down by certain number of pixels, using Javascript is there any way of doing that?

Comment: What do you mean by web page? The contents inside the body tag or just want to scroll down ?

Comment: When you say "move the position of the window or webpage" do you mean to scroll the page and move the viewport?

Comment: scroll down.  And what if the page is resized, how can i calculate the scroll down units?

Answer (score 63):

You can use the following function:

```
window.scrollBy(x,y)
```

e.g.

```
window.scrollBy(0,100)
```

Since you expressed interest in the "units" (I assume you mean width and height, since the units here are pixels!) if a window is resized:

```
document.height
1527

window.innerHeight
912
```

---

*" awesome. But is there anyway to scroll based on if window has been resized? "*

Yes, you can use this event handler:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    window.scrollBy(..., ...);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onresize

Comment: awesome.  But is there anyway to scroll based on if window has been resized?

Comment: yes, `window.onresize`, you may wish to add it to the question while I add it to the answer =)

Answer (score 4):

I've always used jQuery to do this before so if you're interested. . .

The viewport can be scrolled with using scrollTop ( http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ ):

```
 $(window).scrollTop(value)
```

You can find the current offset of an element using offset ( http://api.jquery.com/offset ):

```
$(element).offset().top
```

and you can find out the window's current scroll through scrollTop too:

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

Using those methods you're able to find out the current window's scroll position, determine where you want to scroll to, and scroll from one section to the other using scrollTop, or if you wanted it to be smooth and animated over time — animate ( http://api.jquery.com/animate ).

If you wanted to do an event based on browser resize, then you'd simple bind a function to the resize event:

```
$(window).bind('resize', myfunction);
```