# sliding a page in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html page is divided into many div

```
<div id=1> //content1</div>
<input type="button" value="Go to div 2" />
<div id=2> //content2 </div>
```

My div having id=2 is too below on the page. I want that whenever I click the button the div having id 2 slides up and reaches at the starting of the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147168/how-to-move-the-window-by-x-number-of-pixels-using-javascript/6147261#6147261  my answer in there describes in detail which methods you should be using :)

Comment: Beware of using digits as ids: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/70586#70586)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to simply use an anchor or ID reference and want to animate it, just use [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate).

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zMGnQ/

```
#div1, #div2 {
    height: 400px;
    background: #00aa00;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

<div id='div1'> //content1</div>
<input id='but' type="button" value="Go to div 2" />
<div id='div2'> //content2

$('#but').click(function(){
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#div2').offset().top

    })
})
```

Comment: JohnP... fast and furious as always ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `$("#2").slideUp()` Check [here](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) for more info on JQuery SlideUp()

Comment: That hides the second div, it doesn't scroll to it.